# Determining the big-O of three nested for loops with if statment

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, nested-loops

What is the big-O for the following code :

```
y=1;
x=3;

for(int i =1 ; i < =n ; i*=2)
   for(int j =1; j<= i * i; j++)
      if (i % j == 0)
         for(int k = 1; k<=j; k++) 
            y=y*x;
```

My Thoughts :
Looking at another similar questions I think the inner most loop is `O(n)` and the first loop is `O(log (n))`..as for the middle its `O(n^2)`

so the overall result would be `O(log(n)*n^3)`

Is my answer and way of thinking right ? I'm new to this so i hope i can get some help explaning how this loops work.

Comment: This same question was posted a few weeks ago. Is this from some book?

Answer (score 0):

the most inner loop will run `j` time if `i % j == 0`. As the middle loop will run `i^2` times, only when `j < i` it will be possible to satisfy the specified condition. Hence, among `i^2` iteration of the middle loop, at least `i^2 - i` times, the condition will not be satisfied.

Suppose we denote the number of divisors of `i` with `tau(i)`, among `j < i` only `tau(i)` times the condition will satisfy that means the total complexity of the most inner loop is equal to the sum of divisions of `i` which is at most `77/16 i` ([see this post for the proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1820550/356329)).

Hence, the total complexity of the middle loop with the inner loop is at most `(i^2 - i) + (i - tau(i)) + 77/16 i = i^2 + 77/16 i - tau(i)`.

We also know that the `tau(i)` is in `O(i^(1/loglog(i)))` ([see the proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2496546/356329)). Now, to find the complexity of the whole loop, we need to sum the last expression for `i = 1, 2, 4, ..., n`. As we desire to find the asymptotic complexity and we have a sum here, we can ignore the lower powers of `i`. Therefore, the time complexity of the whole loop is `1 + 2^2 + (2^2)^2 + ... + (2^2)^log(n) = ((2^2)^(log(n)+1)-1)/(2^2-1) = Theta(n^2)`  (a geometric sum with factor of `2^2` and `log(n)` items).

In sum, the higher time complexity analysis for the specified code is `Theta(n^2)` which is also in `O(n^2)` as well.

Comment: Since `i` is always a power of 2, its number of divisors is easy to write down exactly. The condition `i % j == 0` will be true if and only if `j` is a power of 2 and less than or equal to `i`.

Comment: @kaya3 good point. In that case, we can simplify the computation. However, it does not change the final result.

Comment: I'm wondering if it isn't `O(log n * n^2)` since the outer loop runs `log n` times? @OmG

Comment: @user1984 it's right. But, each `log(n)` iteration of the outer loop is not equal to `n^2` iteration of the middle loop. Do you see the point?

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course. I haven't dug deeper into the inner loop analytics. I see you have considered and simplified it.